# InApp browser plugin not working properly in IONIC 5

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

So I am trying to use `in-app-browser` plugin in my ionic app, But when I include it in my `app.module.ts` page it starts throwing error.

Sharing the version of plugin and ionic from my package.json page.

```
 "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^5.29.0",
 "@ionic/angular": "5.0.0",
 "@ionic/core": "5.0.4"
```

this is what I get in my console.

````
Error: Invalid provider for the NgModule 'AppModule' - only instances of Provider and Type are allowed, got: [..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ..., ?[object Object]?]
    at throwInvalidProviderError (core.js:5570)
    at providerToFactory (core.js:11696)
    at providerToRecord (core.js:11667)
    at R3Injector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm5/core.js.R3Injector.processProvider (core.js:11564)
    ```
````

Comment: How are you importing it? is there a ngx in the path?

Comment: @RossRawlins Thanks for this, In my app.module I had not used ngx, I think that was the issue. If you want you can put this as an answer and Ill accept it

Answer (score 0):

first you must install it:

> npm install @ionic-native/in-app-browser

this is a library so you must call it on your  app.module.ts  at your import section

then you'll be able to use it like this

```
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx';

constructor(private iab: InAppBrowser) { }
```

if need more info https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser

Comment: Hi, I have done the above steps that's why I was getting the build error. that happens after I include in the app.module.ts

Comment: What i think the issue is that the app.mudle does not accept the object format that inappBrowser is in, that's why js is throwing such error

Answer (score 0):

Your path for the library is incorrect you are referencing the old path you need to use the path import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx';

Answer (score 0):

**InAppBrowser and Access HTTP in Ionic5**

**Inappbrowswer install plugin**

ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

npm install @ionic-native/in-app-browser

**app.modeles.ts page add**

import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx';

@NgModule({

providers: [{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy},

```
InAppBrowser
```

components added Import Line

import { InAppBrowser,InAppBrowserOptions } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx';

On Click Method Added

browser(){

```
const options: InAppBrowserOptions = {

  location: 'no',
  clearcache: 'yes',
  zoom: 'yes',
  toolbar: 'yes',
  closebuttoncaption: 'close'
 };


const browser : any = this._iab.create("https://google.com/", '_blank', options);      
browser.on('loadstop').subscribe(event => {
  const navUrl = event.url;
  if (navUrl.includes('success')) {
   browser.close();
  }
 });
```

}

In Html
<button (click)="browser()" >Click To Browse

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).